# Redirect to same UIViewController with different data?

Tags: ios, swift4

### First viewController

[image]

### SecondViewController

[image]

FirstViewControllerCode:

```
     class settingViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var settingTableview: UITableView!
    var settingArray = [settingClass(Name:["General","Privous"],image:["genral","previous"]),
                    settingClass(Name:["Maps","Safari","News","Siri","Photos","GameCenter"],image:["map","safari","news","siri","photos","game"]),
                    settingClass(Name:["Developer"],image:["developer"])
                    ]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return settingArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settingArray[section].Name.count    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 55
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let setCell = settingTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SettingCell", for: indexPath) as! settingCell

    setCell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: settingArray[indexPath.section].image[indexPath.row])
    setCell.settingLabel.text = settingArray[indexPath.section].Name[indexPath.row]

    return setCell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let  vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "descriptionId") as! descriptionViewController
   // vc.arr = descriptionArray[indexPath.section].Name[indexPath.row]

    vc.descriptionArray = [descriptionClass(Name:["About"]),
    descriptionClass(Name:["Language","Dictionary","Bluetooth"]),
    descriptionClass(Name:["Reset"])]

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Settings"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
  }

 }
```

SecondViewController code:

```
    class descriptionViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTableview: UITableView!

var descriptionArray = [descriptionClass]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return descriptionArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return descriptionArray[section].Name.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let descCell = descriptionTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "descriptionCell", for: indexPath) as! descriptionCell
    descCell.descLabel.text = descriptionArray[indexPath.section].Name[indexPath.row]
    return descCell
}
}
```

My question is:when i will click on any row(General,previous,maps,siri etc.) of FirstViewController ,it should move to the SecondViewController with different data.It's like the Setting app in iPhone .How? And how to design my didSelectRowAt ().please help me

> My storyboard Structure:

[image]

Comment: in didselectrow you can send array/dictionary as indexpath.row to SecondViewController

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 

     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "descriptionId") as! descriptionViewController 
     // if you want to send data use  descriptionArray[indexPath.section]
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}
```

and set

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: can you explain me briefly

Comment: see edit ......... note :  give **descriptionViewController**  a storyboard identifier

Comment: i have edited my code inside didSelectRowAt() ,check once why it's nil

Comment: oh didSelectRowAt() this method is not invoking

Comment: you need to set the delegate

Comment: ya already added  delegate inside viewDidLoad(){  settingTableview.delegate = self }

Comment: Thank you very much ,Every thing is working fine .But here i am not using any segue so how to use back button in my descriptionViewController,if i am using segue  didSelectRowAt() is not invoking .

Comment: embed the VC inside a navigationController , and you will have back for free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176152/discussion-between-laxmipriya-and-sh-khan).

Comment: see edit ... my storyboard structure so how  it will work on adding navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Add a button in your viewcontroller. Create a segue from your button to the same viewcontroller. The button here is only used for creating the (self) segue, you can hide the button. You will have something like this in your storyboard:

[image]

In you code you can navigate to your viewcontroller by calling:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueSelf", sender: self)
```

Comment: yes already added the segue using storyboard ,and its working fine

Comment: but how can i change the second  tableview data based on different cell click inside First viewController

Comment: you need to pass some object to your view controller. Since you are navigating to self, your object should be of the same datatype but with different data. You can pass the data by overriding 'prepareForSegue' method of the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You should use @HAK's answer to perform segue and add this code to your `settingsViewController` to send data.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let dest = destination as? descriptionViewController{
              dest.descriptionArray = //Your detailed data
         }
    }
```

Note: You could need to write `tableView.reloadData()` in `descriptionViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` method